# How does ice freeze people mid-air in Mortal Kombat?

Tags: mortal-kombat

In every Mortal Kombat game, the characters with ice moves are able to completely freeze their opponents in-air, keeping them from falling and crashing on the floor.

**How do they do this? What about their abilities allows them to defy gravity while they're in affect?**

I know I'm not the first person to ask this question, but so far I've only found speculation and attempts at real-world science. What I want is a canon explanation for how these fighters are able to suspend others off of the ground by only shooting frozen water at them.

Please use only official sources in your answers.

Comment: Also, how is it possible for a person who was frozen solid to then spring back to normal and in fighting condition?  Also, how does the frozen thing fly across the screen, shouldn't it fall on the ground or dissipate in the air?

Comment: In a world where a 4 armed man is normal... what is "abnormal"?

Answer (score 10):

### Because, erm, magic.

Sub-Zero's special ability is based on his possession and mastery of *the element of cold*, one of a range of elemental ***magical*** powers on display in the franchise.

Since his ability already defies our normal understanding of physics, there's really no good reason why it shouldn't freeze someone in mid-air as easily as it would bring them crashing to the ground.

[image]

You might wish to note that another of Mortal Kombat's *elemental specialists* (Rayden) has the ability to fly at his opponents in a way that seems to ***defy gravity.***

Comment: The *"at his mercy"* part seems to sell it the most. Keeps it vague enough to be anything.